# Как правильно подключать шрифты в андроид?

Tags: java, android

Как правильно подключать шрифты в андроид?

Answer (score 5):

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/androidnation.ttf");
textView .setTypeface(font);
```

Но стоит учитывать, что обращение каждый раз к папке assets это "дорогостоящая" операция, поэтому советую вам создать класс singleton, который будет хранить ссылки на уже подключенные шрифты. Либо воспользуйтесь библиотекой [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy), которая это все уже делает за вас. Вот хорошая статья на хабре [как подключать шрифты](https://habrahabr.ru/post/315478/)

Comment: я подключаю через xml,Проблема в том в более старых версиях андроида,приложение подтупливает.Это  из за того что я постоянно тяну из assets?

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appname);
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/epimodem.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

В папку assets ложите ваш шрифт epimodem.ttf

Comment: я подключаю через xml,вот пример:  <com.saabr.administrator.enbekkz.myservice_classes.api_classes.TextViewPlus
            foo:customFont="myfont.ttf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Войти"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/open" />

Comment: Проблема в том в более старых версиях андрода,приложение подтупливает

Comment: Так оно у вас наверное и не кешируется, а каждый раз обращается к папке assets. Воспользуйтесь библиотекой, там вообще делов мало

Comment: Спасибо за профессиональный ответ!